# cordova-background-geolocation-plugin don't giving any response in cordova android app

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

i am using cordova-background-geolocation-plugin in cordova android using voltbuilder the plugin configure successfully but when running code in debug console it is not showing any output

Here is the plugin configuration in config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-background-geolocation-plugin">
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
        <!-- <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" /> -->
        <!-- <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/ic_launcher" /> -->
        <!-- <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="${PACKAGE_NAME}.account" />
        <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="${PACKAGE_NAME}" /> -->
        <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App requires background tracking " />
        <variable name="MOTION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App requires motion detection" /> 
    </plugin>

<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />
        <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
        <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
        <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
            <application android:exported="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/uses-permission" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/> 
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
        </edit-config>
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="resources/android/icon.png"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="resources/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="resources/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    </platform>
```

and here is the sample code i am trying to check

## **Code**

```
 BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
        locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
        desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
        stationaryRadius: 50,
        distanceFilter: 50,
        notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
        notificationText: 'enabled',
        debug: true,
        interval: 10000,
        fastestInterval: 5000,
        activitiesInterval: 10000,
      });
```

## **Output**

`Promise {<pending>}`

## **Code**

```
window.BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus(function(status) {
              console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service is running', status.isRunning);
              console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation services enabled',status.locationServicesEnabled);
              console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation auth status: ' + status.authorization);
            });
```

## **Output**

undefined

i had tried this plugin every combination

```
<plugin name="cordova-background-geolocation-plugin">
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
        <!-- <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" /> -->
        <!-- <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/ic_launcher" /> -->
        <!-- <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="${PACKAGE_NAME}.account" />
        <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="${PACKAGE_NAME}" /> -->
        <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App requires background tracking " />
        <variable name="MOTION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App requires motion detection" /> 
    </plugin>
```

[https://github.com/haylltd/cordova-background-geolocation-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com)

and i had also tried this plugin but voltbuilder made it deprecated

**mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation**